# HtmlAgilityPack get all elements that have an a tag nested

Tags: c#, css-selectors, html-agility-pack

> This is using HtmlAgilityPack . I need to get tr tags with a class of body11  that contain an a tag.I need to access with one of the cells in the row but only for the tags that have a link.have not been having much luck
>   [image]

```
   var tablerows = table.SelectNodes("tr[@class='body11']");

       foreach(HtmlNode row in tablerows)
        {
            var cells = row.SelectNodes(".//td");

            Console.WriteLine(cells[0].InnerText);


        }
```

> also having issue with  accessing each individual cell. Currently prints out multiple cells at the same time

```
                          SReason:
                          Contract Ended
                                                    Pay Rate:
                          $73.58
                                                    Date Created
                                                            :
                                                        09/05/2017



                          Sup:
                          Health Carousel LLC
                                                    Bill Rate:
                          $73.58
                                                    Date Filled:
                          09/07/2017


                          City:
                          Los Angeles
                                                    OT Rate:
                          $110.37
                                                    Date Start:

                              09/03/2017
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector `tr.body11 > td > a` should work for you. This will select any `<a>` node nested in a `<td>` nested in a `<tr>` that has the class "body11".

This will select you  nodes. If you need access to the  or , you'll need to traverse up the node graph.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: i tried this -> table.SelectNodes("tr.body11>td>a")and table.SelectNodes("tr[@class='body11']td/a") so im not sure how this is suppose to be formatted